# show pagination in a javascript tabs

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code that allows me to show and hide tabs but my problem is when the user clicks on a link in the last tab it shows the first one. In another way the result of my clicks are hiden by the other tab.

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return       
        }
        else{             
        $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Show the relevant HTML, please.

Comment: well this is the php file

Comment: @YounessHousni Why do you think it matter that your code is in a php file? Also, javascript shouldn't be in php files. Php should be in there :)

Answer (score 0):

This `$('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn();` is where I think your problem is. That is some very messed up code. Without seeing your markup, I'm not even sure what you were trying to do, but that isn't it. Anyway, you ended up trying to do that because your solution is messy to begin with. See my example below. I only do what is necessary...no need to add ids and attributes to everything to hide/show the appropriate things.

Here is a light and simple way to accomplish what you're looking for. [Live demo (click here).](http://jsbin.com/eYiqAVa/1/edit)

sample markup:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <a>Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Tab3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Tab1 Content</div>
    <div>Tab2 Content</div>
    <div>Tab3 Content</div>
  </div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".content div").not(':first').hide();

  var $content = $('.content');

  $('.tabs a').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    var $selected = $('div:eq('+index+')', $content);
    $('div', $content).not($selected).hide();
    $selected.show();
  });

});
```

Comment: thks for the answer i realy apreciate here is a link to what my problem realy look's like in consulter tab http://onee.p.ht/agent.php

Comment: @YounessHousni if this answer isn't helpful (you haven't clicked the accept checkmark) I'm going to delete it. Please let me know.